# Split string into variables and use output as element

Tags: perl

Well.. I'm stuck again. I've read up quite a few topic with similar problems but not finding a solution for mine. I have a ; delimited csv file and the strings at the 8th column ($elements[7]) is as following: "aaaa;bb;cccc;ddddd;eeee;fffff;gg;". What i'm trying is to split the string based on ; and capture the outputs to variables. Then use those variables in the main csv file in their own column.

So now the file is like:

3d;2f;7j;8k;4s;2b;5g;"aaaa;bb;cccc;ddddd;eeee;fffff;gg;";4g;1a;5g;2g;7h;3d;2f;7j
3c;9k;5l;4g;1a;5g;3d;"aaaa;bb;cccc;ddddd;eeee;fffff;gg;";4g;1a;5g;2g;7h;3d;2f;7j
4g;1a;5g;2g;7h;3d;8k;"aaaa;bb;cccc;ddddd;eeee;fffff;gg;";3d;2f;7j;8k;4s;2b;4g;1a

And i want it like:

3d;2f;7j;8k;4s;2b;5g;4g;1a;5g;2g;7h;3d;2f;7j;aaaa;bb;cccc;ddddd;eeee;fffff;gg
3c;9k;5l;4g;1a;5g;3d;4g;1a;5g;2g;7h;3d;2f;7j;aaaa;bb;cccc;ddddd;eeee;fffff;gg;
4g;1a;5g;2g;7h;3d;8k;3d;2f;7j;8k;4s;2b;4g;1a;aaaa;bb;cccc;ddddd;eeee;fffff;gg;

This is my code i've been trying it with. I know.. it's terrible! But i'm hoping someone can help me?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $inputfile  = shift || die "Give files\n";
my $outputfile = shift || die "Give output\n";

open my $INFILE,  '<', $inputfile   or die "In use / Not found :$!\n";
open my $OUTFILE, '>', $outputfile  or die "In use :$!\n";

while (<$INFILE>) {
  s/"//g;
  my @elements = split /;/, $_;

    my ($varA, $varB, $varC, $varD, $varE, $varF, $varG, $varH) split (';', $elements[10]);
        $elements[16] = $varA;
        $elements[17] = $varB;
        $elements[18] = $varC;
        $elements[19] = $varD; 
        $elements[20] = $varE;
        $elements[21] = $varF;
        $elements[22] = $varG;
        $elements[23] = $varH;

my $output_line = join(";", @elements);
print $OUTFILE $output_line;
}

close $INFILE;
close $OUTFILE;

exit 0;
```

I'm confused about the my statement as well, it shouldn't be possible right? I mean the $vars are in a closed part so it shouldn't be possible to write them to $elements?

**EDIT**

This is how i adjusted the code with TLP's suggestions:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV;

my $inputfile  = shift || die "Give files\n";
my $outputfile = shift || die "Give output\n";

open my $INFILE,  '<', $inputfile   or die "In use / Not found :$!\n";
open my $OUTFILE, '>', $outputfile  or die "In use :$!\n";

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({  # create a csv object
    sep_char => ";",    # delimiter
    eol => "\n",        # adds newline to print
});

while (my $row = $csv->getline($INFILE)) {      # $row is an array ref
my $line = splice(@$row, 10, 1);            # remove 8th line
$csv->parse($line);                         # parse the line
push @$row, $csv->fields();                 # push newly parsed fields onto       main array
$csv->print($OUTFILE, $row);
}

close $INFILE;
close $OUTFILE;

exit 0;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a CSV module, e.g. [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aCSV) to parse your data. Here's a brief example on how it can be done. You can replace the file handles I used below with your own.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({     # create a csv object
        sep_char => ";",   # delimiter
        eol => "\n",       # adds newline to print
    });

while (my $row = $csv->getline(*DATA)) {   # $row is an array ref
    my $line = splice(@$row, 7, 1);   # remove 8th line
    $csv->parse($line);               # parse the line
    push @$row, $csv->fields();       # push newly parsed fields onto main array
    $csv->print(*STDOUT, $row);
}

__DATA__
3d;2f;7j;8k;4s;2b;5g;"aaaa;bb;cccc;ddddd;eeee;fffff;gg;";4g;1a;5g;2g;7h;3d;2f;7j
3c;9k;5l;4g;1a;5g;3d;"aaaa;bb;cccc;ddddd;eeee;fffff;gg;";4g;1a;5g;2g;7h;3d;2f;7j
4g;1a;5g;2g;7h;3d;8k;"aaaa;bb;cccc;ddddd;eeee;fffff;gg;";3d;2f;7j;8k;4s;2b;4g;1a
```

**Output:**

```
3d;2f;7j;8k;4s;2b;5g;4g;1a;5g;2g;7h;3d;2f;7j;aaaa;bb;cccc;ddddd;eeee;fffff;gg;
3c;9k;5l;4g;1a;5g;3d;4g;1a;5g;2g;7h;3d;2f;7j;aaaa;bb;cccc;ddddd;eeee;fffff;gg;
4g;1a;5g;2g;7h;3d;8k;3d;2f;7j;8k;4s;2b;4g;1a;aaaa;bb;cccc;ddddd;eeee;fffff;gg;
```

Comment: I should really take a look at the Text::CSV module in perl! This is gonna take me some time to figure out.. But how do i combine it with the user input/output file part of the code? Because the real file is not 3 lines but 200/400k lines.

Comment: @Nickname27 Like I said, you can replace the file handles `*DATA` and `*STDOUT` with your own, e.g. `$INFILE` and `$OUTFILE`.

Comment: It worked.. Except the only output i got were the first 2 lines.

Comment: The while loop may break if Text::CSV finds a line which is cannot parse. If your input is irregular, you can use a regular loop and instead use `$csv->parse` and `$cvs->fields`, although it will cause a performance drop. If performance is important, you may also want to use the XS version, Text::CSV_XS.

Comment: No, performance isn't an issue. Figuring out how where to begin with a regular loop however is. I don't know how to do that i'm afraid. Is it possible to show me how?